# Oracle ADF - Print input form values in console

Tags: forms, jsf, oracle-adf

I am working in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0. I am creating a simple form application in ADF.
I need to print the input values of the ADF-form in the console. For this, I used the below code.

```
    System.out.println("It1 : " +  it1.getValue());
    System.out.println("si1 : " +  si1.getValue());
    System.out.println("soc1 : " +  soc1.getValue());
```

The input values are getting populated in the console for RichInputText**(it1)** field and RichSelectItem**(si1)** field. But, the same is not working for RichSelectOneChoice**(soc1)** field.

How to print the value that is selected in RichSelectOneChoice**(soc1)** field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using the method you mentioned you should get the required selected value:

```
System.out.println("soc1 : " +  soc1.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the component to the managed bean (actually,this is considered as a bad practice), but to bind only the component values.

So, your form should consist of (for example):

```
<af:inputText value="#{managedBean.inputTextValue}" id="it1" />
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{managedBean.selectOneChoiceValue}" id="soc1">
   <af:selectItem itemValue="first" itemLabel="First" id="si1" /> 
   <af:selectItem itemValue="second" itemLabel="Second" id="si2" />
   <af:selectItem itemValue="third" itemLabel="Third" id="si3" />
</af:selectOneChoice>
<af:commandButton actionListener="#{managedBean.printValues}" id="cb1" />
```

And in the managed bean you should have :

```
private String inputTextValue;

private String selectOneChoiceValue;

//accessors

public void printValues(ActionEvent event) {
   System.out.println("Input text value: " + inputTextValue);
   System.out.println("Select one choice value: " + selectOneChoiceValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute valuePassThru to true and you should get the value of selectOneChoice as well.